# How to remove Image Magick

Tags: ubuntu-store

I've recently installed a few apps from the Ubuntu store, and also Teams and Viber with .deb. But for some reason I have this unknown program called Image Magick what I want to remove. I tried checking the store in the "Installed" section to remove it there, but it doesn't pop up there. Any solution?

Comment: Show me `dpkg -l *magic* | grep ii`.

Comment: It must be a dependency of some other package. You can't remove it.

Answer (score 2):

For removing a program, open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt remove imagemagick
```

or whichever program you want to get rid of.
Please be aware that the program might have been installed because other programs depend on it. Please be especially careful not to remove system-relevant programs.

About `imagemagick`: this is an image manipulation tool. It allows e.g. resizing, converting, combining or splitting images. Quite a nice thing if you ask me, but can be removed without harming your system.

Comment: You should purge, not remove.

Comment: I ran the command successfully, but it's still there. I tried restarting, but it's still there and I can open it.